# erosion function in c++ not giving any output

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to implement a function that erodes a picture without using the built in erosion function in opencv.

My approach is to check if there are any 0's in the image area and if the kernel is one then I can't set the one, which means the condition is false.
Then my second if statement means that the condition is true then my 1 is set .

```
void erosion(const cv::Mat& image, cv::Mat& erosion_image, const cv::Mat& kernel)
{
    bool check;
    int count;
    int count_2;
    int anchorx = kernel.rows / (2.0);
    int anchory = kernel.cols / (2.0);
    for (int x = 0; x < image.rows; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++) {
            kernel.at<uchar>(x, y);
            for (int count = 0; count < kernel.rows; count++) {
                for (int count_2 = 0; count_2 < kernel.cols; count_2++) {

                    if (image.at<uchar>(x + count, y + count_2) == 0 && kernel.at<uchar>(count, count_2) == 1) {

                        check = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (check) {

                erosion_image.at<uchar>(x, y) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is this the right approach?
thank you in advance

Comment: What's `b3`? Why is it only written? On the other hand `check` is never written to... You should verify and improve your [mcve].

Comment: sorry I meant check not b3 I have edited t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is define of erosion for binary images. If you process grayscale image you should set a pixel value to minimum value of the points in its neighborhood [Wiki-Erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)#Grayscale_erosion).

In following code instead of maximum pixel value 1 i used 255 - default for OpenCV maximum value of CV_8U image type.

Note, you also need to choose how to process border pixels of image. In following code they just not processed.
The erosion for binary image can be represented as something like that:

```
void erosion(const cv::Mat& image, cv::Mat& erosion_image, const cv::Mat& kernel)
{
    bool check;
    int count;
    int count_2;
    int anchorx = kernel.rows / (2.0);
    int anchory = kernel.cols / (2.0);
    for (int x = anchorx; x < image.rows - anchorx; x++) {
        for (int y = anchory; y < image.cols - anchory; y++) {
            check = true;
            if (image.at<uchar>(x, y))
            {
                for (int count = 0; count < kernel.rows && check; count++) {
                    for (int count_2 = 0; count_2 < kernel.cols && check; count_2++) {

                        if (image.at<uchar>(x - anchorx + count, y - anchory + count_2) == 0 &&
                            kernel.at<uchar>(count, count_2) == 1) {
                            erosion_image.at<uchar>(x, y) = 0;
                            check = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (check) 
                    erosion_image.at<uchar>(x, y) = 255;
            }
            else
                erosion_image.at<uchar>(x, y) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a few questions regarding the code. why do we use image.rows -anchor x and image.cols -anchory? . Why do we set check to true beneath the for loop?     And `for (int count = 0; count < kernel.rows && check; count++)` why does count have to be smaller than check?     Could you please explain the last two if statements? Thank you for your time

Comment: "image.rows - anchorx" and "image.cols - anchory" are used for prevent access to values out of image boundaries. I set "check" to "true" when start process next pixel because it could be equal "false" from previous iteration.  "count" shouldn't be smaller than "check". This condition means that "count" is smaller than "kernel.rows" and "check" is "true". "Check" should be "true", because we should not check other neighbors if found one with 0 value.

Comment: The `if (image.at<uchar>(x, y))`  needed for process only non-zero pixels. The `if (check)` needed for setting pixel to value, if neighborhood haven’t zero pixels.